# Add more automatic options to the "Declining because..." dialog

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, rejection-reasons

I'll skip the bugs in the dialog; hopefully they will be fixed as it is tweaked.

What I would like to request is that we have a couple more canned reasons.  Just about the only reason why I hit the "Other" option is to supply one of the following rejection reasons:

- Deleting your question would penalize those who made the effort to help you.

  - Used when someone wants to delete a question because they are ashamed of how dumb or simple it is
- You can provide an answer and (after a waiting period) select it as correct to close the question

  - Used when someone wants to delete an already answered question as they have solved it themselves

Comment: I like the first one, but the second one is better "disputed" not declined.

Comment: @Robert That'd require someone to dispute it, though, which requires going through the 10k tools instead of the mod dashboard if no one else has done it. Nevermind that a moderator forcing a flag into being disputed before handling it... something just feels sketchy about that.

Comment: What I mean is dismissing a flag without affecting flag weight.

Comment: @Robert Which can only be done with someone disputing it. Bringing us back to the earlier issue.

Comment: Some options are not going to make sense without giving mods the ability to dismiss without prejudice.  For the second example, I leave a comment under the flagged answer.

Comment: I agree, on the condition that the first reason be renamed "*Your question is bad and you should **feel** bad!*"

Answer (score 2):

Here's two more I commonly use:

- **Unfortunately, your flag requested something the software doesn't support**

  - Example of flag: request to merge two answers, where both answers have upvotes

- **Unclear what action flagger is requesting mods to take**

  - Example of flag: "Question should be edited"

Comment: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention" probably suffices for the latter, but a "learn 2 edit" decline reason would be handy. Time for a pro-forma decline reason script...

Comment: @Shog9 - I would *love* a pro forma flag script. And as for the second, well, that's just one of the many examples I've come across where I couldn't figure out what the flagger wanted done. I could list more examples all day long, but they all pretty much come down to: what on earth did you want me to do?

Comment: We could probably add a "whatidonteven" reason and handle a lot of these...